# Correlation Coefficient between discrete and continuous: is it possible?

Tags: correlation, continuous-data, discrete-data

Is it correct to measure the correlation coefficient between a continuous variable and a discrete variable? I visualized it and there is definitely no linear relationship the way I see it that is why I decided that it was not possible to calculate the correlation coefficient for it. These are the two variables I am working with show on a marginal graph.  [image]

Comment: What is x in your case ?

Comment: Y-area of apartment
x-Number of bedrooms-discrete (1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: By applying the formula you can demonstrate it *is* possible to compute a correlation coefficient: all you need are pairs of numbers.  What it means depends on what the values of $x$ and $y$ represent.  And whether it's appropriate to do the calculation at all depends on your analytical objectives.  Consider, then, editing your question to include such information.

Comment: Such a correlation would indicate something about [stochastic ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering) over the pairs, but further consideration is needed.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but why wouldn't you consider the number of bedrooms as continuous ?

Answer (score 0):

Following on from whuber's answer, perhaps your question should be - can I make reliable inference about the correlation coefficient (for example a p-value associated with a test for r = 0)?  I guess that you are worried that the data will not be bivariate-Normal because "bedrooms" is discrete, but in practice most variables used in correlation analysis will be ordered discrete (even your "area of apartment" is likely recorded to the nearest m^2) the issue is the number of levels.  5 levels, with most of the data concentrated in one of them, could be rather 'chunky'.  If you are worried about this then you could use a non-parametric correlation coefficient or use a permutation test for r = 0.  However, given that a bedroom will have non-zero floor area, there is no question that there will be a significant correlation - as long as the sample size is big enough.  What would be more interesting is whether your correlation is different from, e.g. those in another city/country (could use bootstrapping to estimate a confidence interval for r) or whether the relationship is non-linear.  Perhaps you should embrace the discrete nature of bedrooms and analyze this as an ANOVA with ordered factor.  With that you can test for linear or polynomial effects.